# Why do i have four different default versions of python on my ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, python, python3, alternatives

Im new to linux and im struggling with the alternative install management for python.
I managed to change the default python versions for sudo and root (if i understand it correctly). However i would like to change the default versions of root and sudo for python3 as well, since thats what im installing my venvs with.

Any ideas on how to fix this, are highly appreciated :)
[image]

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: Okay, will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python3` is usually just a symlink to another executable. You can get the location with `whereis python3`, it's the first entry. For me, its `/usr/bin/python3`. It seems like for you, it's different for your user and for root, so execute `whereis` using sudo and without.

`ls -l /usr/bin/python3` shows you the the target of that symlink. For me, it's this:
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec 13 12:55 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.9`

The target is the file `python3.9`, also residing in `/usr/bin`. For you, it's likely to be `python3.6`.

You can change the version by replacing the target of that symlink.
To verify the name of the correct target, check `ls -Al /usr/bin | grep python`.

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -f -s python3.9 python3
```

If the owner of the `python3` symlink is your user, omit `sudo`.

Comment: That solved it, thanks for your effort :) Very well explained as well!