# Can't make python3 as default python instead of python2

Tags: python3, version

I am using Ubuntu. I want to make python3 be the default python version instead of python2. I tried many ways.

For example :

> Open your .bashrc file nano ~/.bashrc. Type
>
> ```
> alias python='python3'
> alias pip='pip3'
> ```
>
> on to a new line at the top of the file then save the file with
> ctrl+o and close the file with ctrl+x. Then, back at your command line
> type source ~/.bashrc. Now your alias should be permanent.

I also tried :

```
update-alternatives --remove python /usr/bin/python2
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3
```

But the problem didn't solve. How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Please say which operating system you are using (which distribution)

Comment: Also, what exactly is the problem, and how does it manifest itself?

Comment: see my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630018/282466), that might help you. `/usr/bin/python` is usually just a symlink as well.

Comment: Be careful, I forced an upgrade once and nearly broke the installation because Ubuntu relies on a particular version. I managed to recover, but it was a pita. There is a python version manager which allow you to select which python environment to use for development, this avoids fiddling with the default installation.

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 2):

Use a python version manager, don't fiddle with the OS dependent version.

Read the readme file at [this repository](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for further information.